# Is it legal to use google news rss in a mobile application?

Tags: android, rss-reader, google-news

I am building a News App.Is it ok to use Google news rss feed for my app.Is it free or they charge for it?

Comment: Upvoted because the question is useful and the answer is equally good! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look here at [Google's ToS](https://policies.google.com/terms). That should give you an idea of what you are / are not allowed to do.

However, I would advise you to check with an attorney or someone else who is qualified to give you legal advice.

Edit: On a closer look at the Google News ToS [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/terms_google_news.html) it looks like you may not use this service for commercial reasons.

Again, you should check with an attorney because it looks like Google has changed their terms a few times and their latest ToS page (March 2020) does not refer to the specific Google News Terms of Service I linked earlier (which is from 2006).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Saved me a lot of trouble.